# How to make a a polygon using only the outer points with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, computer-vision

[Manually made example image of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um2Dt.jpg)

I'm getting list of corner coordinates every time an object moves. I want to make a fillpoly with those coordinates so that I can make make a mask of only the object that is moving. The problem is that the corner coordinates are not in order so the polylines goes to random points regardless of the previous point and there are also corners inside the object. I need only the outer corners of the object so that I can make an outline and fill it. Any help will be welcomed, thank you guys in advance.

Comment: The answer posted gives you what you need to find the bounding poly fitting all of those points. If you need to keep track of the order you can assign them an angle based on the center of the image, and make the 0 angle something you can reference (for e.g. the corners most far apart or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`convexhull()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convexhull#convexhull) function.

Here's a [python tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) and a [C++ tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html) on it, that I thought was a better explanation.

NOTE that this won't give you exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps it is close enough for your application

Comment: Thanks, I still need to reduce the noise. But what you gave me is exactly what I was looking for.